# JQuery Tooltip doesn't work after ajax load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code on my site:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.tooltip-game').jBox('Tooltip', {
    closeOnMouseleave: true,
    ajax: {
      url: 'tooltips/tooltip-game-html.jsp',
      reload: true,
      getData: 'data-ajax',
      setContent: true,
      spinner: true
    }
  });

  $( '#tabs-1' ).tabs({
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
      ui.panel.html('<div style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><img src="images/loading.gif" />');
      ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
        ui.panel.html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible." );
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I use jQuery Tabs and jQuery tooltips, but after loading external file with ajax, tooltips don't work. I know i have to use .on() function, but I don't know how :(

Thank you very much for your tips.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize tooltips after asynchronous call ends.

```
 function tooltips() {              
  $('.tooltip-game').jBox('Tooltip', {
    closeOnMouseleave: true,
    ajax: {
      url: 'tooltips/tooltip-game-html.jsp',
      reload: true,
      getData: 'data-ajax',
      setContent: true,
      spinner: true,
     //Take a look to this line
      success: function() {
            tooltips();
      }
    }
  });
 }    


  $( '#tabs-1' ).tabs({
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
      ui.panel.html('<div style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><img src="images/loading.gif" />');
      ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
        ui.panel.html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible." );
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but it sill doesn't work for me. I don't know how to make load : function :( I searched but I'm little bit lost.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the parameters of load function. The documentation said that `load` function is triggered after a remote tab is loaded: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-load So this should be working

Comment: I tried this before, still didnt work. But thank you very much for yout time, I will keep trying to make it work :)

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle.net I help you better. Maybe your console throws errors.

Comment: Yes, console throws "ui.jqXHR is undefined". Line with "ui.jqXHR.success(function() {"

Comment: We need the event of jBox plugin. I'll search for it

Comment: I edited my answer. I remove the load function and add the `success` in the jBox. According with documentation: http://stephanwagner.me/jBox/options#ajax you can add all jquery ajax options: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Your fiddle never works because you are making an ajax call but there's no response. There isn't any elements with the tooltip class. Please, see the edited code that works

Comment: Tooltip classes elements are inside external files with urls on HTML lines 27, 31, 43 and 47. I dont know how to simulate it in jsfiddle. The urls are correct, but fiddle cant load them.

Comment: You can't load crossdomain resources by ajax. You need to make a trick

Comment: Yes, I tried but still doesn't work. But console is clear, not thowing anything. Should not I use something with $( ".selector" ).on( "tabsload", function( event, ui ) {} ); ?

Comment: Try it, I don't know. Console is clear, but did you receive the ajax call correctly? In network tab.

Comment: Finally I have it. Thank you for put me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm here first day, I clicked that your answer was useful, but It didn't show my vote, because I have not 15 reputations :)